# go install revel cmd after dep ensure not work

Tags: revel

I want to solve a problem about vendoring.
After dep ensure, the packages are installed under the vendor folder

But go install github.com/revel/cmd/revel doens't work unlike the revel document says

Of course, the Gopkg.toml includes it and the package exists under the vendor folder.

I think this is related to GOPATH. There is no way to search for packages under the vendor on CLI.

How can I handle it?

go install github.com/revel/cmd/revel

Error message :

```
can't load package: package github.com/revel/cmd/revel: cannot find package "github.com/revel/cmd/revel" in any of:
        C:\Go\src\github.com\revel\cmd\revel (from $GOROOT)
        C:\GoCode\src\github.com\revel\cmd\revel (from $GOPATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm dep in installed

```
go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
```

Make sure inside your gopkg.toml you got

```
require =[
        ...
        "github.com/revel/revel",
        ...
]
```

Then

```
GO111MODULE=off dep ensure
GO111MODULE=off revel run
```